# How to hide SurfaceView when button is clicked?

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

I want to do is,in an activity with `SurfaceView` that open Camera,and preview inside it.After click a button,the `SurfaceView` stop/invisible,so the image capture will shown on the `ImageView` in the activity.

Is as the diagram below:

[image]

So I have a custom camera activity which have the XML like below,

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surface_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/showImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</FrameLayout>
```

What I wanna to do is,when I click on the floating button,the `SurfaceView` disappear,`ImageView` visible,then the image that taken by the camera shown on the `ImageView`.

**So what I have tried so far**

```
 public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
 SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    Camera mCamera;
    Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback;

    ImageView showImage;
    FloatingActionButton btnCamera;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        btnCamera = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
        showImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.showImage);

        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //here when click the camera button
                //camera take photo
                //surface view disappear
                //preview image shown on image view
                mCamera.takePicture(null,null,jpegCallback);
                showImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                surfaceView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
        });

        jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
                File file_image = getDirs();

                if(!file_image.exists() && !file_image.mkdirs()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed to save picture",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
                String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
                String photofile = "myphotos" + date+ ".jpg";
                String file_name = file_image.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + photofile;
                File picFile = new File(file_name);
                Bitmap bitmap = null;

                try{
                    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(picFile);
                    outputStream.write(data);
                    outputStream.close();

                    //here set the picture capture to the image view
                    //convert it to bitmap,setBitmap to the imageView
                    bitmap = decodeFile(picFile,10);

                    if(bitmap !=null){
                        showImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this,
                                "Picture Captured Successfully:", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this,
                                "Failed to Capture the picture. kindly Try Again:",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                } catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Picture saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                refreshCamera();
            }
        };
    }

    private void refreshCamera() {
        if(surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null){
            return;
        }

        //stop the camera preview
        try{
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //start camera again
        try{
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        //open camera
        try{
            mCamera = Camera.open();
        }catch (RuntimeException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        Camera.Parameters parameters;
        parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
        parameters.setPreviewSize(352,288);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

        try{
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        refreshCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera= null;
    }
   }
```

After trying this,what I got now is,the screen is totally blank.`SurfaceView` is invisible,`ImageView` with preview of the image taken from camera not shown out.
But I checked `file_name` and `bitmap` is having value in the log.

So I  tried,to not set the `SurfaceView` to invisible like below:

```
btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cameraImage();
            showImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //surfaceView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
    });
```

The image can shown on the on the top on surface view like below,but  if I set the surface view to invisible,the whole screen appear blank.

[image]

But I want the surface view disappear,only the ImageView available.

Answer (score 0):

Moving following line (*to make surface view invisible*),

```
surfaceView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

from `onClick(View v)` method to `onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)` method would solve the problem.

But, that would result in camera `release` and it must be opened again to capture another picture.

Comment: when I make the surfaceView invisible,the screen become blank..only white color on the screen